# MySQL Join 2 tables with duplicate rows but prioritise rows from left table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. One is a generic price list for all customers, the other is a special price list for selected customers.

An example of them:

Special List

```
ID | STOCK_CODE | PRICING_REF | PRICE
1  | 1234       | CUST001     | 1.00
2  | 1235       | CUST001     | 2.00
```

Generic List

```
ID | STOCK_CODE | PRICE
1  | 1234       | 4.99
2  | 1241       | 4.99
3  | 1249       | 5.99
```

I would like to joint the 2, which I am currently doing. However, rather than have just one list displayed I'd like to merge the 2 but only show the price from the special list, if the stock code matches and there is a price available in that row.

My statement so far is:

`SELECT * FROM stock s LEFT JOIN price p ON p.stock_code = s.stock_code WHERE PRICING_REF = '$pricing_ref' AND s.stock_code = '$ref'`

This only returns the price of items from the special list, missing the remaining items from the generic list.

Currently, if I do a search for items : `'%1%'` it will return stock_code `1234` and `1235`, but not `1241` and `1249` which I'd also like included. However, the price for `1234` must come from the `Special List`, not the `Generic List`.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want all the rows from `special` and then non-matching ones from `generic`.  If so:

```
select ID, STOCK_CODE, PRICE
from special
union all
select ID, STOCK_CODE, PRICE
from generic g
where not exists (select 1 from special s where g.stock_code = s.stock_code)
```

Comment: I think you're pointing me in the right direction. I'd like to make wildcard searches against the data which could be in either table, how would I implement that?

Comment: @MikeF . . . You would use this as a subquery and then a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank you. I'm now getting a #1222 error because there are different number of columns in each. I need to be able to select `PRICING_REF` from the special table and `DESCRIPTION` and `LAST_SALE_DATE` from the generic table. I don't think a UNION ALL is going to help with this, do you?

Comment: @MikeF . . . You have to include the columns in both subqueries, giving them NULL values.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand what I need to do.

Comment: Ok, I don't think this is going to work as intended. If a match is made on the `special` table, then I still need it to get the `description` from the generic table. Using `NULL` values means the `description` is empty.

Comment: @MikeF . . . In that case, one of the subqueries might need a join for that situation.